# Flex item width not resizing in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a load of 'tiles' and am having trouble in internet explorer - most/all other browsers seem to be fine. The problem is, I want the tiles to only be 4 per row on desktop and 2 per row on mobiles, but in IE the other tiles just squeeze in on the same row rather than dropping to the next line.

The width of flex items doesn't seem to work, and should be 23.5% (on desktop) and 48.5% on mobiles. Can someone explain what's going on here? It seems that IE does not like contemporary code!

```css
/* Flex Tests */
.sad-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    width: 23.5%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) { margin-left: 2% }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(n+5) { margin-top: 2% }
.flex-item-image-link { width: 100% }
.flex-item img {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.flex-item, .flex-text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial; /* perhaps remove */
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-text-content { padding: 10px }
.flex-item .flex-text.header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-item .flex-text.header a { color: #000 }
.flex-item .flex-text.price {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: grey;
}
.flex-item .flex-text.description {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-height: 6em; /* limits to 3 lines of text */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-item .flex-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}
.flex-item .flex-btn:hover { opacity: 0.7 }
.flex-item ul { text-align: left }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) { margin-left: 3% }
    .flex-item { width: 48.5% }
    .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(even)) { margin-left: 0 }
    .flex-item:nth-of-type(n+3) { margin-top: 3% }
}
/* IE FIXES */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .sad-flex {
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-item {
        -ms-flex: 1;
    }
    .flex-item * { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div class="sad-flex">

    <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
    

<div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support the `flex: flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis` shorthand.

You need to change it to `flex-grow`.

For example this

```
flex: 1 2 30px;
```

should be replaced with this

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 2;
flex-basis: 30px;
```

In your case

```
.flex-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
/* Flex Tests */
.sad-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    width: 23.5%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) { margin-left: 2% }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(n+5) { margin-top: 2% }
.flex-item-image-link { width: 100% }
.flex-item img {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.flex-item, .flex-text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial; /* perhaps remove */
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-text-content { padding: 10px }
.flex-item .flex-text.header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-item .flex-text.header a { color: #000 }
.flex-item .flex-text.price {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: grey;
}
.flex-item .flex-text.description {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-height: 6em; /* limits to 3 lines of text */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-item .flex-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}
.flex-item .flex-btn:hover { opacity: 0.7 }
.flex-item ul { text-align: left }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) { margin-left: 3% }
    .flex-item { width: 48.5% }
    .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(even)) { margin-left: 0 }
    .flex-item:nth-of-type(n+3) { margin-top: 3% }
}
/* IE FIXES */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .sad-flex {
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-item {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    .flex-item * { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div class="sad-flex">

    <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
    

<div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="/shop/i/turtle/"><img style='background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133394/pexels-photo-133394.jpeg");' src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#">textko</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">$12.34</span>
        <span class="flex-text description">text here text here text here text here text here text heret ext here .</span>
    </div>
    <button class="flex-btn" onclick="#'">button</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: was the flex-grow: 1; the only thing you changed? funny, because on our actual test site, making the exact same change to the exact same code doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: Yes, it's the only change. You might have a different CSS rule that overrides it. Check your entire CSS code.

Comment: Nothing is overriding it, and as soon as -ms-flex: 1 is removed, the content is much too large. The flex-grow: 1 also makes no difference. I'm stumped, as you've demonstrated it working here...

Comment: Make sure you change all your flex shorthands, maybe now the flex behavior is working for these items but broken for others...